# Read the content of a file to memory, result different from 32bit os and 64bit os

Tags: c, fread

I wrote a function below to read the content of a file to memory.
It works well on my local machine(Ubuntu 32bit), but it produces wrong result on server(CentOS 64bit).

***Wrong case:***
With a 40 byte file, the content is below, on the 64bit os, it gave me wrong result.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

***The code:***

```
char* file_get_contents(const char *filename) {
  FILE *stream = NULL;
  char *content = NULL;
  size_t ret;
  struct stat st;

  if ((stream = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", filename);
    exit(1002);
  }

  if(stat(filename, &st) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to stat file %s\n", filename);
    exit(1002);
  }

  content = malloc(st.st_size);
  ret = fread(content, 1, st.st_size, stream);

  if (ret != st.st_size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read file %s\n", filename);
    exit(1002);
  }

  fclose(stream);
  return content;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong output? Did you terminated `content` with `'\0'`?

Comment: @Rohan Yes, the wrong result is not terminated right. But why it works well in the 32bit OS?

Comment: @xdazz Mostly luck, perhaps there happened to be a zero byte in the memory after the piece malloc() gave you, while that memory contained something else on your other platform.

Comment: @nos But only file with 40 bytes gives the wrong result, others are ok, it is strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `file_get_contents` cannot be correctly used by its caller. It returns a char * but not its lenght, nor does it return a string (i.e. it isn't null terminated.).

As long as you're reading text, do e.g.

```
  content = malloc(st.st_size + 1); // + 1 here for the nul terminator
  ret = fread(content, 1, st.st_size, stream);

  if (ret != st.st_size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read file %s\n", filename);
    exit(1002);
  }
  content[st.st_size] = 0; //nul terminate
```

Comment: The file has 39 `a`, and `st.st_size` is `40`, the string length should be 39, why i need to `+1` ?

Comment: @CyberDem0n But There is no `\n` in the file.

Comment: @xdazz Then something is misdiagnosed somewhere. Does `wc -c thefile` actually give you 39 ? Perhaps there's another garbage/non-printable character after all the a's. (Check with `od -t x1  thefile` )What does ls -l say ? And how/where are you printing out st.st_size ?

Comment: @nos Sorry, you are right. `wc -c thefile` gives 40. Did you know why `echo 'a' > foo` that make the file contains `\n`?

Comment: That's what echo does, it adds a newline. use `echo -n a >foo` to omit the newline.